# Append to a Solr Index

Tags: solr, indexing

This may be a trivial question but I am trying to append to an existing Solr index and seem to be overwriting what is there every time. I have two databases that I am getting data from and I can import data from each database individually but when I import data from one then immediately import data from the second one, the first is overwritten. I have two dataSources mapped in my db-config.xml file and I am using the standard Admin UI to run the import. My config file looks like this.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource 
    name="ds-1"
    type="JdbcDataSource" 
    driver="Driver"
    url="jdbc_url1" 
    user="user1" 
    password="pass1"/>

<dataSource
    name="ds-2"
    type="JdbcDataSource" 
    driver="Driver"
    url="jdbc_url2" 
    user="user2" 
    password="pass2"/>

   <document>

 <entity name="entity1" dataSource="ds-1" query="SELECT YYY  FROM TABLE">
      ...
    </entity>

 <entity name="entity2" dataSource="ds-2" query="SELECT ZZZ FROM TABLE">
      ...
    </entity>

  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

What can I do to prevent the original index from being overwritten. I want to incrementally add data from a variety of different sources all the time so having my indexs get wiped does me now good.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are probably defining the key for your indexed documents to be the primary key id from the database and the values are overlapping. In order to prevent this, you will need to specify a unique id for Solr. Typically when I have run into this issue in the past, I have used a string field as the id field and append a character or two to the id from the database to make it unique. Example: items from Product Table would have ids like P1, P2, etc. and items from Orders Table would have ids like O1, O2, etc.

You should be able to use the Data Import Handler [TemplateTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#TemplateTransformer) to help accomplish this for you.

Comment: Hey thanks @Paige Cook... I have an id field that is a unique id to every record in every database I have. Should I specify that field within the <entity> tag as a "pk" type?

Comment: Ughh...I was naming the field something identical in both databases so the facets names were the same. It was working correctly all along. Thanks for the quick reply though!